# MySQL query for get image url from post in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, wordpress

```
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_status = 'publish'
   AND ID IN (

       SELECT object_id
         FROM wp_term_relationships
        WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (

              SELECT term_taxonomy_id
                FROM wp_term_taxonomy
               WHERE taxonomy = 'category'
                 AND term_id IN (

                     SELECT term_id
                       FROM wp_terms
                      WHERE name = 'artikel'
                     )
              )
       )
```

I want to get image url in the post too. Can you give me example code? Thanks for helping me. Sorry bad english.

Comment: 1. See JOIN. 2. Do not attempt anything else until step 1 is complete.

Answer (score -1):

use this wordpress function to get post image url pass the post id to function it result the url of image. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

```
wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
```